# ProgressView wont update in tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to update a custom tableview cell's progressview but the progress view wont update.

I can set the labels on the tableview cell but accessing things like progress bars or activity indicators doesnt work.

I do the following on the custom cell

```
cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
cell.progressView.progress = 0.5;
[cell.progressView setNeedsDisplay];
```

This doesnt work even though in the debugger I see the object is of the correct cell type and the progressView is allocated.

I have tried setNeedsDisplay on the cell itself as well, but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Show your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It's possible you are setting this up incorrectly. One common issue is adding the custom views over and over to a cell.

Comment: before posting the code, could it be that I am calling CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? I then use this cell pointer to set the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` is most likely the problem because this likely results in another cell being dequeued from the table. So you end up setting up a new cell, not the one currently being display.

Instead, do this:

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This directly asks the table for the cell. This should return the currently displayed cell if the row is visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me out. My activity indicator appeared too. :)